# Trouble with duplicating a transaction's functionality

Tags: c#, sql, transactions

I'm updating a current program that is working and in use on a Live environment, it saves Customers and Orders then exports them to an old database as well.  All of the Reporting is still done in the old system while the reporting system in the new system is in development, which is why these all need to be exported.

This program has a built-in C# TransactionManager that is used to group multiple calls from C# to SQL within one transaction.  Whenever I try to duplicate this I get errors and can't get it working.

Here's the code that is in place, working:

```
using (ITransactionInfo trx = this.TransactionManager.BeginTransaction())
{
    //
    // Update the customer. If the customer doesn't exist, then create a new one.
    //
    this.SaveCustomer(Order);

    //
    // Save the Order.
    //
    this.Store.SaveCorporateOrder(Order, ServiceContext.UserId);

    //
    // Save the Order notes and the customer notes.
    //
    this.NotesService.AppendNotes(NoteObjectTypes.CorporateOrder, Order.Id, Order.OrderNotes);
    this.NotesService.AppendNotes(NoteObjectTypes.Customer, Order.Customer.Id, Order.CustomerNotes);

    //
    // Export the Order if it's new.
    //
    this.ExportOrder(Order, lastSavedVersion);

    //
    // Commit the transaction.
    //
    trx.Commit();
}
```

All of these functions just format the data and send parameters to Stored Procedures in the DB that perform the Select / Insert / Update operations on the DB.

The SaveCustomer stored procedure saves the customer to the new database.

The SaveCorporateOrder stored procedure gets information that was writen by the Save Customer stored procedure and uses it to save the Order to the new database.

The ExportOrder stored procedure gets information that was written by both of the previous ones and exports the Order to the old database.

Each of these stored procedures contain code that starts a new transaction if @@TRANCOUNT == 0 and have a commit statement at the end.  It appears that none of these are being used because of the transaction in C#, but there is no code that passes transaction information or connection information to the stored procedures that I can see.  This is working and in use on a SQL 2005 server.

When I try to build this and use it on my development environment that uses SQL 2008R2, I get errors like

```
"Uncommittable transaction is detected at the end of the batch"
```

and

```
"The server failed to resume the transaction"
```

It appears that each one is starting it's own transaction and is unable to read the data from the previous, uncommitted transaction instead of seeing that it is in the same transaction.  I don't know if the different SQL version could be causing this to work differently or not, but the exact same code works in the Live install but not on my Dev environment.

Any ideas, or even direction where to look next would be wonderfull!

Thanks!
-Jacob

Answer (score 0):

I think that the problem is because transaction fails and is not rejected. You don't have rollback call for the situation when any of SQL queries fail. Have you checked those queries?

Comment: I've checked the SQL queries and the logic in each is wrapped in a Try block with a Rollback call in the Catch.  None of the C# methods have a Rollback call in the whole program, but these transactions are getting rolled back so I assume there's some time of auto-rollback built into the TransactionManager.